# Запросы к бд, что бы спросить несколько вариантов из бд

Tags: php, mysql

Есть файл Excel, в одной из ячеек которого лежат категории, разделенные запятыми. Мне нужно получить ID этих категорий из БД. Через запрос можно получить ID одной категории:

```
SELECT ID FROM `b_iblock_section` WHERE name Like '".$cat."'"
```

Как мне получить оба ID из базы?

Comment: Сейчас значения из ячейки я вытащил в массив вида [0] => Первая категория [1] => Вторая категория

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, '".$cat."')`

Comment: Этот запрос мне через Foreach прогонять или сделать его на массив $cat

Comment: В `$cat` должна быть та самая строка со значениями, разделёнными запятыми. Мог бы и сам описание функции посмотреть...

Comment: Делаю, потом вот так
$group = $connection->query($result);
$res = $group->fetch();
print_r($res["ID"]);
И получаю только один ID

Comment: Я удалённой отладкой (тем более не своего кода) заниматься не буду. Смотрите текст запроса, выполняйте его на консоли, смотрите результат, корректируйте код.